# Using of "ddns-confgen" versus "rndc-confgen"

Tags: dhcp, bind

I created a key by rndc-confgen, put it into name.conf to use rndc for bind9 server. Works fine. By a mistake of mine, i used the same key on isc-dhcp-server for ddns.  Later i noticed that, but also DDNS works fine. So, what is the difference between ddns-confgen and rndc-confgen? I seems to me, they doing the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, rndc key and ddns key completely different reason. But, at the end, both key files have the same TSIG content. So using, rndc key for ddns or vis versa is not the idea, but works.